# Seaborn Time-Series Plot

Tags: pandas, time-series, seaborn

I have a Dataframe train_data_new with a column pickup_datetime from which i extracted just the date portion:

```
train_data_new['pickup_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(train_data_new.pickup_datetime)
train_data_new['pickup_date'] = train_data_new['pickup_datetime'].dt.date
train_data_new.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

Next I have created another Dataframe that groups rides by pickup_date:
And I am trying to visualize this with tsplot:

```
vendor_date = pd.DataFrame(train_data_new.groupby(['vendor_id','pickup_date'])['id'].count())
vendor_date.reset_index(inplace = True)
vendor_date['unit'] = 1
sns.tsplot(data = vendor_date, time = "pickup_date", value = 'id', unit = 'vendor_id', condition = "vendor_id")

       vendor_id pickup_date    id  unit
0            1  2016-01-01  3048     1
1            1  2016-01-02  2887     1
2            1  2016-01-03  2895     1
3            1  2016-01-04  3164     1
4            1  2016-01-05  3304     1
5            1  2016-01-06  3412     1
6            1  2016-01-07  3607     1
```

But I get an error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'

What am I doing wrong here? Please suggest! Thanks

Comment: can you post a sample DataFrame?

Comment: Using the provided dataframe it seems to be working. The issue could be that you are using `train_data_new` as input and not `vendor_date`.

Comment: No it does not plot pickup_date on the x axis for me.